# Does pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader read a single csv file in parallel on S3?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I am looking at the pyspark docs and using [pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader)

I am wondering though does it process a single csv file in parallel when I give it an S3 path?  How could each of the worker nodes read the same csv file on S3?

Comment: whenever we load file into pyspark from s3 so first of all file dump into local hdfs temp or local system temp.